# Create/Improve a pseudo-terminal using bindings

Tags: java, string, binding, javafx

My goal is to **create a Pseudo-Terminal** that will **show data that I receive**. To create my pseudo-terminal, I use a `TextArea` that I bind to a `StringProperty`. When my `StringProperty` attribute change, my `TextArea` must update its content.

I implement a **first version** that works, it displays every message that I receive, but **content of the TextArea is erased every time I receive new Data**.

*Version 1* :

> In the class that receives the data :

```
StringProperty sendData = new SimpleStringProperty();
WHEN I RECEIVE DATA : sendData.set(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

> In the class that contains the TextArea :

```
@FXML private TextArea consoleTextArea;
public void setLiaison (StringProperty textRecu){
        consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(textRecu);
}
```

> In a third class I initialise everything, and call :

`Controller.setLiaison(sendData);`

I **don't want my textArea to clear everytime** I receive data of course, so I try this :

```
consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(consoleTextArea.getText()).concat("\n").concat(textRecu.get()));
```

But this doesn't work at all, it only display the first message that I receive on my TextArea, then nothing.

Is there another way to keep what's in my TextArea using bind ?

**NB** : I can't use *simple method* like append text, because I use MVC, and my controller(*TextArea*) must be link to my model(*StringProperty*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either* have the `StringProperty` store all the messages concatenated together (instead of the `sendData.set(...)` method you currently have):

```
sendData.set(sendData.get() + Arrays.toString(strings));
```

*or* update the text area by concatenation every time the property changes (instead of the binding you currently have):

```
textRecu.addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> consoleTextArea.appendText(newText));
```

With either of these versions, if you have a lot of text coming in, your performance is eventually going to suffer (as String concatenation is basically a slow process). It might be better, for example, to use an `ObservableList<String>` to hold all the messages, and a `ListView<String>` to display them, removing earlier messages if the list starts to get too full.